# Remove an attachment in emacs org-mode, rather than deleting it

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can only see [commands](http://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html) to delete a tasks attachments in org-mode after calling the dispatcher with `C-c C-a`. Is there a way to simply unattach these files (or directory) from the project or task? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-mode`'s ways of attaching things is putting them in a folder
associated with the heading.
To my knowledge, there's no way to do what you ask with this system:
a file either is in a folder or it isn't.
On the other hand, you could open the attachment directory
with <kbd>C-c C-a f</kbd> and move this file where ever you want.
To `org-mode`'s knowledge, it will be deleted.

Comment: I see, this is convenient except that using Windows I can't store links in there, so I have to move/copy associated files to that directory. If I were using that directory as a repository that would be fine, but I am not. I think this is actually a new question - how to link in windows/orgmode.

Comment: You basically answered the question as I asked it above, thanks for explaining the attachment functionality.